# gulp command not return to shell

Tags: gulp

I have a gulp script, and when I run it from command line, it does not return to shell.

this is a simple gulp command to delete files from dist directory

```
'use strict';

var del = require('del');
var gulp = require('gulp');
gulp.task('clean', function (cb) {
    return del(['dist/**/*'], cb);
});
```

run command:

```
gulp clean
[13:39:10] Using gulpfile gulpfile.js
[13:39:10] Starting 'clean'...
[13:39:11] Finished 'clean' after 6.35 ms
npm WARN package.json abc@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json abc@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json abc@0.0.0 No README data
npm WARN package.json karma-coverage@0.2.7 No README data
npm WARN package.json karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.4 No README data
```

it does not return to shell, I have to do CTRL+C to return back to shell.
I am new to gulp, please let me know what I did wrong, thanks.

Comment: Your Gulp tasks looks good and should work fine, I'm irritaded about the warnings, though. How's your application folder structure? What files do you have in dist before cleaning? Do any other processes run?

Comment: I'm with @ddprrt, the warnings are odd.  That's what you'd see when you run an `npm install` typically.  I just replicated this and everything appears to work correctly from my end.  Something else is going on.  You also might try intercepting the callback from `del` to see if it's passing any errors ie: `return del(['dist/**/*'], function(errors){console.log(errors); cb();};`

Comment: there is a line in my gulpfile.js doing this: // always execute to update npm & bower components
    gulp.src(['./bower.json', './package.json'])
        .pipe(install()); removing this it will not trying to do install, gulp clean
[13:39:10] Using gulpfile gulpfile.js
[13:39:10] Starting 'clean'...
[13:39:11] Finished 'clean' after 6.35 ms but it still does not return to shell, I have to do CTRL+C.

Comment: the above is in clean.js under gulp directory. my gulpfile.js looks like the following: (if I move content of clean.js to this file it correctly returns to shell, so looks like it has something to do with calling another gulp file)                                                                                                             (function () {
    'use strict';

    var gulp = require('gulp');
    require('require-dir')('./gulp');
}());

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the callback argument.

```
gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return del(['dist/**/*']);
});
```